# Oracle ADF is Licensed or Free ware?

Tags: oracle-adf

I need to know whether we can use oracle adf with free of cost.
i found some other sites they are saying ADF Essential is free ware.

If it is licensed by oracle , How much the license cost?

Answer (score 1):

ADF essentials is license free, running on glassfish, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentials-1719844.html).

From the main oracle page:

> Oracle ADF Essentials is an end-to-end Java EE framework that
>   simplifies application development by providing out-of-the-box
>   infrastructure services and a visual and declarative development
>   experience. Oracle ADF Essentials is free to develop and deploy.

And further, from the FAQ:

> Oracle ADF Essentials is a free packaging of key technologies from the
>   Oracle Application Development Framework that can be used to develop
>   and deploy applications without licensing costs.

Not to be snarky, but what part of **Free** and **without licensing** is unclear?